# Hibernate: Program run persists new created entities together with entities which were persisted in previous program run and which I had deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle-xe

This is maybe a beginner question on hibernate. I am doing my first steps, I designed a simple datamodel consisting of about 10 entities and I use hibernate to persist them to my Oracle XE database. Now I am facing the following problem: First time, when I do a transaction to persist some entities, they are persisted properly. I verify, that the data exists in the database and then I delete all the entries from all database tables. I verify that all tables are empty again. Then I run my program again to persist some new entities - and here happens something really strange: Afterwards I find in my databse the new entries as well as the old ones, which were persisted last time and which I had deleted! They contained the old IDs and the old data fields! How can this be? This happens even if I shut down my computer after the first time the program runs! How does it remember the old entries and where are they saved? Do you have any ideas?

---

Some information, that might be useful:

I am using annotations (instead of config files) for the mapping.

Following you see the classes used for persisting as well as one example of an entity (I am showing only one entity to avoid making the question too long).

As you see, I am using FetchType = `EAGER` on my `MANY` to `MANY` mappings (as I understand, this makes sure, that all related entities are loaded immediately together with any loaded entity). Can this have any impact?

Thanks for any help!

```
public class PersistenceManager {
    private static final SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
    public static void sampleData() {

        try(Session session = factory.openSession()) {
            SampleDataLoader.loadSampleData(session);
        } catch(HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception during persisting! Message: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public class SampleDataLoader {

    static void loadSampleData(Session session) {

        Language french = new Language("French");
        Language german = new Language("German");

        Noun garcon = new Noun(french, "garcon", false);
        Noun junge = new Noun(german, "Junge", false);

        junge.addTranslation(garcon);

        ZUser user = new ZUser("Daniel", "password");
        user.setOwnLanguage(german);
        user.setEmail("abc@somemail.de");
        user.setDateRegistered(LocalDateTime.now());

        user.addForeignLanguage(french);

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.save(french);
        session.save(german);
        session.save(junge);
        transaction.commit();

    }
}

@Entity
public class ZUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String picturePath;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime dateRegistered;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNLANGUAGE_ID")
    private Language ownLanguage;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name="USER_LANGUAGE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="LANGUAGE_ID")
    )
    private Set<Language> foreignLanguages = new HashSet<>();

    public ZUser() {  }
    public ZUser(String n, String p) {
        name = n;
        password = p;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
    public String getPicturePath() { return picturePath; }
    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) { this.picturePath = picturePath; }
    public LocalDateTime getDateRegistered() { return dateRegistered; }
    public void setDateRegistered(LocalDateTime dateRegistered) { this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered; }
    public Language getOwnLanguage() { return ownLanguage; }
    public void setOwnLanguage(Language ownLanguage) { this.ownLanguage = ownLanguage; }
    public void addForeignLanguage(Language language) {foreignLanguages.add(language);}
    public Set<Language> getForeignLanguages() {return Collections.unmodifiableSet(foreignLanguages); }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you simply forgot to commit after deleting?

Comment: No, unfortunately not: I veryfied, that all tables were empty again, SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM SOMETABLE was 0 for all tables. But thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: ah, but now that you mention it: I probably should say that I did not use hibernate to delete them, I used the SQL command line of the oracle database ... may this play a role?

Comment: Well, if you delete in Oracle and then don't commit then no wonder direct select return 0 rows within the same session. Please make sure you commit.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clarified by the comment of Jagger (see comments). Indeed, I was using Oracle SQL command line to delete the entries and I had rgotten, that I need to explicitely commit after deleting. The solution can be so easy :)